# In C: error when I compile

Tags: c

I keep getting this error, "error: use of undeclared identifier", Ive searched all over and they tell me that I haven't declared 'nbr'. and i have. the point of this is to make a pointer that points to the value of a integer, and you must be able to set the value of the integer with the pointer, I'm really lost here... if someone can explain in depth that'll be great. see code below... thanks...

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_ft(int *nbr)
{
int a;
*nbr = a;
}
int main()
{
ft_ft(*nbr);
return 0;
}
```

side note: i cant use stdio.h and i cant use other .c or .h files. and i cant add any other functions.

Comment: If you have declared it then you are not showing it. If this is your actual code, please explain where you declared nbr

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Please indent your code and read abut C scoping rules.

Answer (score 5):

```
int main()
{
  ft_ft(*nbr);
  return 0;
}
```

This is where execution starts, and nbr has not been defined, except inside the scope of ft_ft(), as a parameter to be passed in. A variable needs a definition and a value before it makes sense to pass it into a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <unistd.h>       // declare a whole bunch of identifiers you never use

void    ft_ft(int *nbr)   // declare the identifiers ft_ft, and nbr
                          // ft_ft scope is the whole file from this point onwards
                          // nbr's scope is the ft_ft function
{
int a;                    // declare the identifier a
                          // a's scope is from here to the end of the function at the next }
*nbr = a;                 // use nbr and a
}
int main()                // declare the identifier main with scope to the end of the file
{
ft_ft(*nbr);              // use the declared identifier ft_ft
                          // with an undeclared nbr
return 0;
}
```